# Swap /dev/mapper/* devices

Tags: partition, lvm, devices

I have been given a box that has /dev/mapper/root mounted as / and mapped to /dev/dm-0. It has /dev/mapper/home mounted as /home and mapped to /dev/dm-2. The dm-0 device is 5G and the dm-2 device is 2T. I've been asked to swap them: make / 2T and /home 5G. I have resized, deleted, and added logical volumes. Is there a way to swap logical volumes?

In case it matters... They want to use this as a database server. The database is in /var/lib/mysql, which is under /, which only has 5G and is already 80% full. /home is 1% full.

Comment: There's no easy way to _swap_ volumes just like that, you'll have to repeat what you have already done: resize, delete, add, etc. Btw, if the 2TB /home is currently 1% full, that's still 20GB and too big for the 5GB /home  you're aiming at.

Comment: Thanks. I've made a proposal that they let me simply place the database in /home instead of /var/lib. No mucking around and it will just work. Hopefully they see the light.

Comment: the "traditional" way of doing this is to move and symlink.  e.g. `mkdir -p /home/var/lib`, do whatever your init requires to stop mysql, `mv /var/lib/mysql /home/var/lib/`, `ln -s /home/var/lib/mysql/ /var/lib` and then restart mysql.   Alternatively, paranoia dictates that it is safer to cp or rsync /var/lib/mysql to /home/var/lib/, then rename /var/lib/mysql to /var/lib/mysql.old and then create the symlink.  When you're sure it's working OK, you can delete /var/lib/mysql.old...this avoids the (tiny) risk that the `mv` operation might fail part-way through, leaving you a mess to clean up.

Comment: in either case, whether copying/rsyncing or moving, mysql MUST be stopped while the transfer is in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way to swap two devices, but this isn't what you need anyway. Keep `root` as `/` and `home` as `/home`, shrink `home` to the desired smaller size, and enlarge `root` using the space that was freed up.

Depending on the filesystems, you may or may not need to unmount them to resize them. Ext4 filesystems can be enlarged while mounted, but not shrunk; use the command [`resize2fs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/resize2fs.8.html). [Btrfs filesystems can be resized in either direction while mounted](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch03s03.html).

To shrink an LVM logical volume, use [`lvreduce`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvreduce.8.html). Make sure that you don't accidentally shrink it smaller than the filesystem — this is the one step here where an incorrect manipulation can cause data loss (and it's very likely to do so if you get the number wrong). Be careful, with LVM, lowercase suffixes (`k`, `m`, `g`, …) use powers of 1024, but uppercase suffixes (`K`, `M`, `G`, …) use powers of 1000. To enlarge an LVM logical volume, use [`lvextend`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvextend.8.html).

For example, with ext4:

```
umount /home
resize2fs /dev/mapper/home 5G
lvreduce -L 5g /dev/mapper/home    # note lowercase g
lvextend 2t /dev/mapper/root
resize2fs /dev/mapper/root
```

Note that if `/home` is really 2TB and is 1% full, it won't fit in 5GB. Adjust sizes accordingly.

Alternatively, you may want to move the database to a filesystem of its own. It's often a good idea to use separate volumes for the operating system and for large datasets, because they can have different storage policies (regarding redundancy, performance, backups, etc.). If that server is only a database server, it would make sense for it to have two filesystems: `/` (including the `/home` directories which don't contain much more than the administrators' configuration files) and `/var/lib/mysql`.